# Distribution of funds between pre-tax and ROTH for a under 30 years old

Tags: 401k, retirement, roth-401k

What is the usual contribution percentage for an under 30 years? I am trying to change mine but I am not sure how much what I should change it to.

- equal distribution between ROTH and pre-tax
- or more pre-tax and less ROTH or vice versa

My current ratios:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Distribution of funds between pre-tax and ROTH for a under 30 years old?**
>
> What is the usual contribution percentage for an under 30 years?

The decision regarding the split isn't based on age. It is based on your income, and how you think your income tax rates will compare in the future.

While the IRS does release the [marginal tax rates each year](https://www.kiplinger.com/taxes/tax-brackets/603738/irs-releases-income-tax-brackets-for-2022), you have to determine how those tax rates impact your income. The published rates are only assessed against your taxable income.

That number is your gross income minus things such things as your health insurance premiums paid from your paycheck. You also subtract from your gross income your health savings Account and flexible spending account contributions.

You also have to subtract out either your standard deduction or you itemized deductions.

But don't forget to add in income from interest and dividends from your taxable bank and investment accounts.

Your tax filing status is also important.   For example when your taxable income as single tax filer in 2022 hits $89,076 you have entered the 24% marginal tax bracket. But if are married filing jointly, and your families taxable income was that same number, you would only be barely into the 22% tax bracket which runs from $83,551 to $178,150.

To know where you fall your will have to do some calculations. If the income for that tax year falls into the lower brackets, then Roth makes the most sense. But if your income is in the upper brackets, traditional makes the most sense. Then you have to guess if the rates in the future for you and your family will be higher or lower.

As you can see this isn't age dependent. It is based on your gross income, your deductions and your tax status.

Comment: I'm at 200k. I'm should have added this to the question. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Node.JS At 200k per year, contributing 11% of your income (8% traditional, 3% roth) you will end up contributing 22k per year which currently exceeds the legal contribution limit of 19.5k for 2021, and 20.5k for 2022. I may be wrong here, but you might have a larger problem than a percentage distribution between ROTH and Traditional